# z-index for child of sibling

Tags: css, z-index

Within main, I have two siblings - card & popup. When the button is clicked in the card, popup needs to show over the card. I use absolute for popup. However, button needs to be display also in the popup in order to be toggled. I want button, as a descendant of the card, to be display over the popup. Using the z-index didn't help me. I don't think duplicating the button (each sibling to have one) is good solution.

```
<main className="main relative">
  <section className="card">
    <footer className="card__footer">
      <div  className="card__footerWrapper">
        <div className="card__shareBtn">...</div>
      </div>       
    </footer>
  </section>
  <div className="popup absolute">...</div>
</main>
```

Comment: please include [mcve] (css)

Comment: sharebtn also needs to be absolute. Both will have same offset parent so zindex will work as expected.